# Multiple AsyncTask - how do I know which one it is in 'onPostExecute'

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm downloading three JSON objects in parallel via 3 three parallel AsyncTask:

```
            dictAsync1Task = new DictAsyncTask(DictionaryLookUp.this, "Jishoo");
            dictAsync1Task.execute();

            dictAsync2Task = new DictAsyncTask(DictionaryLookUp.this, "Systran");
            dictAsync2Task.execute();

            dictAsync3Task = new DictAsyncTask(DictionaryLookUp.this, "Tatoeba");
            dictAsync3Task.execute();
```

Once a task is done, I want to refresh a ListView in my TabLayout (hey, how do I get those cool grey background rectangles around the commands when I ask a question ?).

Is there a way to know which asyncTasks' onPostExecute I'm currently in ? i.e. I want to refresh the listView via 'switch' by checking whether I'm in onPostExecute of dictAsync1/2/3Task.

(I actually found a better solution by simply using a global variables within AsyncTask, but I'm still curious if there is a way to this the way I described)

Comment: are they all linked to the same ListView?

Comment: you can box tokens by delimiting them between grave accents (these chars: ``) `like this`

Comment: you pass a string in the asynctask constructor. Can you access it in onPostExecute? you can use it to know which asynctask finished running

Comment: @Mercato - no, 3 individual tabbed listviews. @nandsito - ``thanks``, and that's exactly what I did, but I was still curious if there was a way to distinguish them in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` for parallel execution.

If those async classes are static then you have to pass callback or weak reference (to avoid memory leaks) to activity. Forward that downloaded data with type in `onPostExecute` and then refresh only relevant tab list.

prototype can be `void refreshData(Object data,String type);`

You can pass different type of arraylist in data because it's object. You can later check like this

```
if(data != null && ((ArrayList<?>)data).size() > 0)
    {
        if(((ArrayList<?>)data).get(0) instanceof MyType)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

or switch on type and then cast `data` like this `mTab1Data = ((ArrayList<MyType>)data)`

and check if activity is still alive. Maybe use exit app before async completion.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that I actually executed them serially, looks like they changed the behavior, thanks for the pointer on that. I'm not sure I follow the rest, that is a bit too advanced for me I'm afraid, are you trying to pass it beween ``doInBackground`` and ``onPostExecute`` or where would that code go ?

Comment: you can pass that `onPostExecute`. If you need in doInBackground then you have to update ui in runnable like `Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){})`